# How to make the documents writable through the screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, digital-handwritting

I have a web application which generate reports .

I want to allow these reports to be hand writable `on the screen` .

I mean that i can write some notes or sign on those documents through the screen by `Light Pen`.

I don't know where should i begin to implement something like that or the the start point to search from .

I want some searches and libraries to use .

Comment: How do you want to write? Using your mouse? Or touch?

Comment: i guess you are trying to sign the generated reports by mouse !

Comment: Why dont you just open them reports with adobe reader? it has supports for notes.

Comment: i want to know both of them, could you help me with mouse?

Comment: Side note: real signing may not be as easy as just collecting image... you may need some way to validate the fact that the document is the same as the one that signature was added to...

Comment: Just I need to write notes through light pen .

Answer (score 2):

In general speaking, the Canvas can be used to write on web page screen with a tablet or a mouse. Then you send that image on the server with a post back and save it.

read the details on how [Creating an HTML5 canvas painting application](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/)

Here is an example, select the Pencil, and write on. http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example5.html

If you like to make it more complicate, then look at this library:
http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/

is converting what you see on page into canvas (image) on the fly, then you can write on it as image, and then you can post back to the server.

Comment: I 'll use a light pen for this task :: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_pen

Comment: @just_name You can use a wacom tablet.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i ask about the .net issue relayed to the light pen .Is there some library or help to use it in my web application Please ?